# Nodejs/Expressjs Request returns 404 when accessing API

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, request, http-post

I'm trying to access the authorization data for an API and I'm able to successfully get the access data through an ajax call in my browser, but not through using either the request package or the native http request method in Nodejs/Expressjs.

The ajax call:

```
var url = 'https://subdomain.example.com/api/auth';
var data = {
    token: "Data token" // A token representing user credentials
};

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(resp) {
       console.log(resp);
    }
});
```

The nodejs request call:

```
var url = 'https://subdomain.example.com/api/auth';
var data = {
    token: "Data token"
};

app.get('/api', function(req, res) {
    request({
        url: url,
        method: "POST",
        qs: data
    }, function(err, apiRes, apiBody) {
        res.send(apiBody);
    });
});
```

The ajax call returns a page containing the token data that I need to access the rest of the API. I expect to get the same return value from the request in Node, but instead I get an error page saying "404 - File or directory not found. The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." The apiRes object also has 404 statusCode, but I'm not able to access any more data than error info than that.

Is there any reason why an http request would succeed in the browser and not in a server even when they carry the same parameters and url? I've come across the same 404 issue with other URLs in this API, and in those cases I was getting the issue because the API didn't include an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header in its response. I suppose that's a possibility here, but the most detailed error info I can pull from the API response is the status code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you

```
app.get('/api', function(req, res) {
request({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    json: data
}, function(err, apiRes, apiBody) {
    res.send(apiBody);
});
});
```

as per I know POST does not support qs(query string)